# Phonon video player getting stuck on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to  play video using Python Phonon player in my raspberry pi2, it is getting stuck after 2 to 3 seconds at a resolution of video 720 X 480. But the video is smoothly playing the other resolutions 160x200, 320x200, 320x240, 640x200, 640x480. Actual resolution of video is 720 x 480. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        src = Phonon.MediaSource(path + "video1.mp4")
        self.media.setCurrentSource(src)
        self.media.play()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):        
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))

        MainWindow.resize(scr_w, scr_h)
        MainWindow.move(0,-28)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))

        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(MainWindow)
        self.video_widget = Phonon.VideoWidget(self.centralwidget)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video_widget)  
        self.audio_out = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio_out)

        self.video_widget.setGeometry(0, 0, 720, 480)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```